# How does the ability "Flash Fire" work?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Specifically, does a Pokemon with Flash Fire take damage the first time it is hit with a Fire move AFTER which it is immune to Fire moves and gets a damage bonus? Or the first time it is hit with a Fire move will it negate that damage immediately?

I would prefer confirmation from someone who has observed this in game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flash_Fire_(Ability)):

> **Flash Fire** makes the Pokémon immune to Fire-type moves and will activate when hit by one. When activated, the power of the Pokémon's Fire-type moves is increased by 1.5×.
>   While subsequent hits by Fire-type moves will not provide further increase in power, the Pokémon remains immune to their effects.

This means that a Pokemon with Flash Fire is **always** immune to each Fire-type move, the only effect that needs you to be hit by a Fire-type move to be active is the +50% boost on Fire-type attacks.

Answer (score 3):

In all generations, if a pokémon has Flash Fire, it is effectively immune to all Fire-type moves, both damaging moves and status moves (Will-O-Wisp).

In generation 3 and 4, however, if the pokémon with Flash Fire was frozen, it would not activate and the pokémon would take damage. This was changed in gen 5.

Comment: You have observed this yourself? Follow up question - so I could do a double battle with a flash fire pokemon and a pokemon with lava plume, and the lava plume would not damage the fire pokemon (even the first time it hits) but would instead just power up the pokemon with flash fire?

Comment: @nhouser9 Correct. The Flash Fire pokémon would only be powered up the first time, but it would still continue to be immune to Lava Plume as long as it kept the ability. (And even if its ability changes, it would still keep the boost that flash fire gave it)

Answer (score 1):

Flash Fire makes you immune to any Fire move. It also boosts the power of your own Fire moves by 50% after being hit by one, for as long as you stay in.